# Angular - Uncaught error causes re-direct back to base URL

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

With `Angular 7.0.3` (but I believe this has occurred since version 2?), if an uncaught error occurs during run time, the application breaks and causes a redirect back to the base URL specified in `index.html`.

1. Is this the expected *default* behavior from the Router?
2. If so, how can I prevent this redirect from happening?

Ideally, if an error is encountered, I would like to keep the user on the existing page and allow them to continue to navigate through the application ***without*** having to start from the base URL.

I am using lazy-loaded feature modules and have written services similar to the ones found in this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@aleixsuau/error-handling-angular-859d529fa53a) with a dedicated `error.component.ts` component and both:

```
{ path: "error", loadChildren: () => ErrorModule }
```

and

```
{ path: "**", loadChildren: () => ErrorModule }
```

in the base `app-routing.module.ts` file.

For an extremely reduced-test case, this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/error-handling-in-angular-step1) from the tutorial linked, appropriately *catches* the **client error** but only provides the `error.component.ts` view with the option to go back to the home page.

### EDIT: 11/27/2018

My project is setup to use *Just In Time Compilation* rather than AOT. If, for example, I have built the project using `ng build --watch --fork-type-checker` and I remove a closing `</div>` from any component template, the application will error and redirect the user back to the base URL, when navigating to that component's URL.

Is there a way to catch these types of errors ***without*** using AOT and without redirecting the user back to the base URL?

Comment: @SiddAjmera Even if I directly provide any error service in the `app-routing.module.ts`,  the same behavior occurs.

Comment: I wonder how your `ErrorModule` is a lazy loaded module when you have already `import`ed it in your `AppRoutingModule`. Ideally you have to provide a relative path to that module followed by `#ModuleName`. If you `import` the module directly in any file that is not lazily loaded, then the Module itself won't load lazily.

Comment: @SiddAjmera Thank you. To clarify, the lazy loaded modules are for feature modules which follow the `#ModuleName` format. Specifially for the error module, whether it follows that format, the `loadChildren: () => Module` or an explicit import, the re-direct behavior occurs.

Comment: @ntdog22 did you ever find a solution to this?